# react-bootstrap component documentation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm looking for the documentation of **react-bootstrap** components. I see that on the [react-boostrap site](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html) it is available the code to create the components, but what about how to use them, or the parameters they accept?

(for example, if I have a Tab, how can I intercept its onclick? or, does it have an onclick event?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an onClick event, in most cases you can just define it on the element:

```
<Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={alert("you clicked me")}>Default button</Button>
```

There is also documentation [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tabs-props-area), for how to intercept the tab onSelect event using the eventKey method.